# can't open QR url from an alert view in Swift

Tags: swift, uialertview, qr-code, nsurl, func

I'm trying to open a URL from a QR with Swift, but I can't get with the code to do it. I tried with this func code:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        vwQRCode?.frame = CGRectZero
        return
    }

    let objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
        let objBarCode = objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        vwQRCode?.frame = objBarCode.bounds;

        if objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Se ha detectado QR", message: objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abrir Link", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: //nil))

                {action in

                    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.cl")!)
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue))
            }))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click in the button from the alertView just do nothing.
Then I tried with google URL and open with no problem.
Please Someone Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I finally did it.
I just change the "fileURLWithPath" for "string"

Before

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue))
```

After

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue)!)
```

Now with Swift3 in iOS10 openURL is deprecated, but if you change "openURL" for "open" works perfectly.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().open(NSURL(string: objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because the system can't handle the resulting URL. You should check this capability before:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue)
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Does your QR code really lead to a file URL or a web link?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine. Try doing a simple:

```
print(objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue)
```

and see what that returns, as it would suggest this is where your problem lies. Potentially your QR code contains some quotation marks?

Comment: I try your code but do the same thing.
The QR codes contains no quotation marks.